# how to write an unencoded string to a view in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have a controller that adds a JSON string to a model in Spring MVC 3.2:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String myController(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("jsonData", "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}");
    return "views/myView";
}
```

and the view uses the JSON inside a javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething () {
        var myObject = <c:out value="${jsonData}" />;
    }
</script>
```

which would ideally look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething () {
        var myObject = {"foo":"bar"};
    }
</script>
```

but the output is being HTML-encoded, and so looks like this to the browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething () {
        var myObject = {&#034;foo&#034;:&#034;bar&#034;};
    }
</script>
```

How do I prevent the string from being HTML-encoded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use `<c:out>`, since its unique and only effect is precisely to escape HTML special characters:

```
function doSomething () {
    var myObject = ${jsonData};
}
```

Comment: *facepalm*  I knew it was something incredibly simple I was missing.  >;o)  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `<c:out escapeXml="false" value="${jsonData}" />`

Comment: For those looking for answers, this also works, but the accepted answer is simpler.